# How can I suppress automated generation of mailto: tag on email addresses in HTML email

Tags: email, html-email

I am generating HTML with some text that looks like a valid email address, for example john@gmail.com

How do I suppress automatic generation of a mailto: tag when the HTML is opened in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you can do is add your own link (pointing either to something else, or just with an empty #) and style it to look like the surrounding paragraph text. That at least hides the link.